# access file's actual code as string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, smtplib

this is mainly curiosity, I'd like to access my script's actual code, so for a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, subprocess, time, re
import yagmail
```

it would return

```
code = """\
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, subprocess, time, re
import yagmail"""
```

I see nice things like file, name, etc, but no code:

```
__IPYTHON__        __IPYTHON__active  __debug__          __doc__            __file__           __import__         __name__           __package__        
ipdb>
```

Thank you

Comment: Open the source file and read it directly into a string.

Comment: @codyc4321 There is no need for such violence. You can read in a text file in just a couple of lines in Python. Fewer if you ignore PEP8.

Comment: you loaded the python binary, not the scsript...

Comment: So `__file__` didn't even peak your curiosity?

Comment: it just showed the filename. so the fastest way to do this is get filename then read

Comment: `ipdb> __file__
'./automated_emails.py'`
 nothin wrong with that, just thought it may be builtin

Comment: Technically there is a way to edit the source file, using a combination of ast, inspect, imp, and sys in a non-destructive way:
https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy/blob/master/fuckit.py

Of course, just reading it is better from `__file__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inspect` library has some methods for this (specifically `inspect.getsource()`).

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code